# Redirect Form after submit

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, forms

I am using a custom reviews form. After submiting the form I want the user to be directed to a new page saying thank you. Currently it is being redirected by the indexcontroller.php with:

```
$this->_redirectReferer();
```

How would I get it to redirect to a cms page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        /* Redirect to certain url  */
        $this->_redirectUrl($url);
```

if you want to redirect on any page:

```
        $this->_redirect('pageurl');
```

For more information follow the blow url: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-redirect-functions/

Answer (score 0):

Add a new function in your custom controller:

```
public function customAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('path/to/custom.phtml');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Then update `$this->_redirectReferer();` to `$this->_redirect('*/*/custom');`

Create your custom page in : `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/path/to/custom.phtml`

```
<h3>Thanks...<h3>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using below code.

> $url = Mage::getUrl('thank-you'); --> CMS page url key
>
> $this->_redirectUrl($url);